# Mouseless Clipboard Manager

Tags: software-recommendation, shortcut-keys, clipboard, clipboard-manager

There are a lot of clipboard managers available, but I search one which can be used without using the mouse.

Has someone a recommendation for me?

Answer (score 1):

I use [**Diodon**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Diodon) (available from the Software Centre). It keeps a clipboard history of strings that you can access at any moment by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>; you can then select which entry to insert using the arrow keys. You can also change the key combination from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to something else.

Comment: Keyboard shortcut doesn't seem to work with XFCE (Linux Mint)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **Clipit**.

You can find it into official Ubuntu repositories.

It has a combination of hotkeys to use in Preferences.

Look at the picture below -->

[image: Preferences Tab]

Answer (score 1):

You can check [Keepboard](http://sourceforge.net/projects/keepboard/). It provides configurable shortcut keys for activation and other common operations.